# Why is this the wrong move?

Tags: checkmate, beginner, chess.com

I am new to chess. I am playing puzzles on chess.com. I made a move which I thought was checkmate, but it tells me I made the wrong move.

It looks to me like the King is in check by the bishop. But no pieces can take the bishop, and the king has no safe spaces to move to.

[image]

Why is this the wrong move?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just realized, the knight cannot take the bishop, but it can block it!

Answer (score 6):

White can play Ne2 and block the check. Instead, you can play Rd2 which is mate in one.